# Redmine - browse SVN repo on same server

Tags: svn, redmine, svn-ssh

I have Redmine installed on the same server as Subversion. I'd like to hook up my Redmine project to the local repository. I've tried:

1. Creating a "redmine" user, assigning a password and adding the user to the group who owns the SVN repository. And then set the repository's path (e.g. file://data/svn/repositories/MyProject) along with the "redmine" user and its password in Redmine (Settings > Repositories).
2. Adding the user who is running Redmine (www-data via Nginx/Passenger) to the group who owns the SVN repository. And then set the repository's path (e.g. file://data/svn/repositories/MyProject) and clearing out the username and password (in hopes that www-data would be used since it's running Redmine).

But I continue to get: 404 The entry or revision was not found in the repository.

The reason I want to access the repo locally is because SVN is configured to use SVN+SSH, not HTTP- I don't want to configure HTTP and from my research it's not straightforward to get Redmine to work with SVN+SSH.

So, I'd like to know how to get this to work with the local repo OR how to setup SVN+SSH if it's not too difficult/cumbersome/hacky.